# how to decide the Order of records as a Result of join query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

The tables (from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm) 
1)Customers table:

```
 +----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | ADDRESS   | SALARY   |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Ramesh   |  32 | Ahmedabad |  2000.00 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 | Delhi     |  1500.00 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 | Kota      |  2000.00 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 | Mumbai    |  6500.00 |
|  5 | Hardik   |  27 | Bhopal    |  8500.00 |
|  6 | Komal    |  22 | MP        |  4500.00 |
|  7 | Muffy    |  24 | Indore    | 10000.00 |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

2) Orders table :

```
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
|OID  | DATE                | CUSTOMER_ID | AMOUNT |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
| 102 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   3000 |
| 100 | 2009-10-08 00:00:00 |           3 |   1500 |
| 101 | 2009-11-20 00:00:00 |           2 |   1560 |
| 103 | 2008-05-20 00:00:00 |           4 |   2060 |
+-----+---------------------+-------------+--------+
```

the inner join query is :

```
SELECT ID, NAME, AGE, AMOUNT
        FROM CUSTOMERS, ORDERS
        WHERE  CUSTOMERS.ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

The result shown is :

```
+----+----------+-----+--------+
| ID | NAME     | AGE | AMOUNT |
+----+----------+-----+--------+
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 |   3000 |
|  3 | kaushik  |  23 |   1500 |
|  2 | Khilan   |  25 |   1560 |
|  4 | Chaitali |  25 |   2060 |
+----+----------+-----+--------+
```

My question : the resultant table is clearly ordered according to the "ORDERS" table i.e the oredering in ID column in result table is 3,3,2,4 acc. to ORDERS table. Why is the ordering of IDs not according to the CUSTOMERS table i.e why is the result not

```
ID
2
3
3
4
```

and the corresponding values .Is there some sort of rule for that ?

Comment: Unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause, the ordering of the results is arbitrary and unpredictable.

Comment: @Barmar ..so you're saying the result could also have come as 
ID
3
2
3
4
 ?

Comment: Yes, it could have come in any order.

Comment: But isn't there a particular order in which joins are computed by the software? Something like, match 1st row of "customer" with 1st row of "order" ,then match 1st row of"customer" with 2nd row of"order" and so on.. @Barmar

Comment: There is a particular order for every RDBMS, but is implementation specific and can change at any time (i.e. with the next release of the software or when your database changes). You must not rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of a query result is not defined until you define it. Use an `ORDER BY` clause when you are interested in a particular order.

That being said...

- Don't use old style joins anymore. Every RDBMS supports SQL-92 join syntax.
- Get into the habit of prefixing columns with the table name. Use a table alias to save typing.

.

```
SELECT 
  c.ID, c.NAME, c.AGE, o.AMOUNT
FROM 
  CUSTOMERS c
  INNER JOIN ORDERS o ON c.ID = o.CUSTOMER_ID
ORDER BY
  c.ID;
```

Comment: Using join instead of comma, is slow.

Answer (score 3):

You should use order by like below

```
SELECT ID, NAME, AGE, AMOUNT
        FROM CUSTOMERS, ORDERS
        WHERE  CUSTOMERS.ID = ORDERS.CUSTOMER_ID order by ID asc;
```

Comment: if id on't use order by, will the output always be ID 3 3 2 4, and if ,yes. why ? why not ID 2 3 3 4, it seems more logical to me, you compare 1st row of customers with 1st row of order ,then 1st with 2nd,3rd....and so on...in this way, order should come as ID 2 3 3 4. what is the actual method of joining used by sql ?